# Cloning a branch other than master on GitHub

Tags: git, github, clone

On GitHub, if I have two branches, `master` and `master_copy`. Is there are way for me to clone the `master_copy` branch instead of the `master` branch?

Even when I select `master_copy`, when I get the link to the clone the repo, it just gives me the `master` branch link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the branches are in the repository, master and master_copy - this enables git to work distributed without a central server.

After you clone the repo just do the following:

```
git checkout master_copy
```

and you will be using the master_copy branch.

Comment: Also, if you use a command line interface, just add `-b <branch>` to the arguments to make the initial checkout use the given branch, rather than the server-supplied default (usually `master`).